# Conditionally change panel background with facet_grid with stacked/grouped bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I'm modifying a stacked/grouped bar plot and would like to change the panel/background color based on the year. Here's the data that I'm working with, a data frame called melted.

| Year | D_or_I | Value | Scenario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | MPO D | 7350 | MPO |
| 2024 | MPO D | 1671 | MPO |
| 2025 | MPO D | 9454 | MPO |
| 2026 | MPO D | 2415 | MPO |
| 2027 | MPO D | 4250 | MPO |
| 2023 | MPO I | 2166 | MPO |
| 2024 | MPO I | 787 | MPO |
| 2025 | MPO I | 1816 | MPO |
| 2026 | MPO I | 4364 | MPO |
| 2027 | MPO I | 3331 | MPO |
| 2023 | MPOE D | 4121 | MPOE |
| 2024 | MPOE D | 8937 | MPOE |
| 2025 | MPOE D | 9288 | MPOE |
| 2026 | MPOE D | 1861 | MPOE |
| 2027 | MPOE D | 1858 | MPOE |
| 2023 | MPOE I | 7892 | MPOE |
| 2024 | MPOE I | 4408 | MPOE |
| 2025 | MPOE I | 6866 | MPOE |
| 2026 | MPOE I | 405 | MPOE |
| 2027 | MPOE I | 2475 | MPOE |

I have gotten the stacked bars like I want them using the following code.

```
ggplot(melted, aes(x = Scenario, y = Value, fill = D_or_I)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ Year, switch="both") +
  ggtitle("Figure 2. Numbers and Stuff","For your Enjoyment") +
  theme(strip.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 90), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
  legend.position="top",plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=element_blank())) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#2980b9','#3498db','#f39c12','#f1c40f')) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma,breaks = seq(0,20000,2500)) + 
  ylab('Number (unit)') + xlab('Year') +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1,1,1,1, "cm"))
```

Which produces [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sYpq.png).

Now, I'd love to change the color of the background/panel (the part that's light grey) so that it varies for a series of years, say 2023-2025 one color and 2026-2027 a different color. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can draw an infinite `geom_rect` where the fill is determined by the year. This is easier if you use `ggnewscale` to allow two fill scales:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(melted, aes(x = Scenario, y = Value)) + 
  geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, 
            inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(fill = factor(Year)), alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none") +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(aes(, fill = D_or_I), stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + 
  facet_grid(~ Year, switch="both") +
  ggtitle("Figure 2. Numbers and Stuff","For your Enjoyment") +
  theme(strip.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 90), 
        axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        legend.position="top",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=element_blank())) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#2980b9','#3498db','#f39c12','#f1c40f')) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma,breaks = seq(0,20000,2500)) + 
  ylab('Number (unit)') + xlab('Year') +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1,1,1,1, "cm"))
```

[image]